# How to fix problem with Interstitial Ads?

Tags: android, kotlin, ads, splash-screen, interstitial

After opening the application, **SplashScreen** turns on, where **Interstitial Ads** is turned on,
after closing ads the transition to **MainActivity** occurs, everything works but somehow not correctly, after closing ads
the screen turns white for 1-2s and only then starts loading **MainActivity**

**SplashActivity**

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AdMobFullscreenManager.AdMobFullscreenDelegate {
    internal var fullscreenManager: AdMobFullscreenManager? = null

    private val adManager: AdMobFullscreenManager?
        get() {
            if (fullscreenManager == null) {
               configureManager()
            }
            return fullscreenManager
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)

        if (isOnline()) {
            if (!SubscriptionProvider.hasSubscription()) {
                adManager!!.completed()
            } else {
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
                }, 3000)
            }
        } else {
            Handler().postDelayed({
                startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
            }, 3000)
        }

    }

    private fun configureManager() {
   
            if (fullscreenManager == null) {
                fullscreenManager = AdMobFullscreenManager(this, this)
            } else {
                fullscreenManager!!.reloadAd()
            }
        
    }

    override fun ADLoaded() {
            if (adManager!!.tryingShowDone) {
                adManager!!.showAdd()
            } else {
                startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
            }
        
    }

    override fun ADIsClosed() {
            if (adManager!!.tryingShowDone) {
                val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
    }

    fun isOnline(): Boolean {
        val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val netInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
    }

}
```

**AdMobFullscreenManager**

```
class AdMobFullscreenManager(private val context: Context?, delegate: AdMobFullscreenDelegate?) {

    private var countRequestAd: Int = 0

    private var delegate: AdMobFullscreenDelegate? = null
    var tryingShowDone = false
    private var adMobState = AdMobState.Loading
    private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd

    enum class AdMobState {
        Loaded,
        Loading,
        NoAd
    }

    init {
        if (!SubscriptionProvider.hasSubscription()) {
            mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(context)
            configure(delegate)
        }
    }

    private fun configure(delegate: AdMobFullscreenDelegate?) {
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(context?.getString(R.string.interstitial)!!)
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        this.delegate = delegate
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                countRequestAd = 0
                adMobState = AdMobState.Loaded
                if (this@AdMobFullscreenManager.delegate != null) {
                    this@AdMobFullscreenManager.delegate!!.ADLoaded()
                }
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int) {
                if (!SubscriptionProvider.hasSubscription()) {
                    this@AdMobFullscreenManager.reloadAd()
                }
            }

            override fun onAdClosed() {
                if (this@AdMobFullscreenManager.delegate != null) {
                    this@AdMobFullscreenManager.delegate!!.ADIsClosed()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    fun showAdd(): Boolean {
        var b = false
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show()
            b = true
        }
        return b
    }

    fun completed() {
        tryingShowDone = true
        if (adMobState == AdMobState.Loaded) {
            if (delegate != null) {
                if (!SubscriptionProvider.hasSubscription()) {
                    delegate!!.ADLoaded()
                }

            }
        } else if (adMobState == AdMobState.NoAd) {
            if (delegate != null) {
                delegate!!.ADIsClosed()
            }
        }
    }

    fun reloadAd() {
        countRequestAd++
        if (countRequestAd == MAX_REQUEST_AD) {
            adMobState = AdMobState.NoAd
            if (delegate != null) {
                delegate!!.ADIsClosed()
            }
            return
        }

        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            adMobState = AdMobState.Loaded
            mInterstitialAd.show()
        } else if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading()) {
            adMobState = AdMobState.Loading
            if (!SubscriptionProvider.hasSubscription()) {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            }
        }
    }

    interface AdMobFullscreenDelegate {
        fun ADLoaded()
        fun ADIsClosed()
    }

    companion object {
        private val MAX_REQUEST_AD = 3
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="" /> 

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        
        
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:theme="@style/TranslucentTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme" />
    
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**App**

```
class App : Application() {
   
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        sInstance = this

        MobileAds.initialize(this)
    }

    companion object {

        private lateinit var sInstance: App 

        fun getInstance(): App {
            return sInstance
        }

        fun getInstance(activity: Activity): App {
            return activity.application as App 
        }
    }

}
```

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
```

Even if I make it many times easier, for example

**SplashActivity**

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)

        mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)

        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(this.getString(R.string.interstitial))
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show()
                }

            }

            override fun onAdClosed() {
                val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        })

    }

}
```

Nothing changes, the problem remains the same.
At the same time, there are other Interstitial Ads in the application that work well and correctly.
Please tell me what could be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I think the issue comes from `Handler`, try without using it and see if the issue still present

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI As I wrote in the last part, nothing changes either, there is no Handler

Comment: The `MainActivity` start after `SplashScreen` right ? try : 
`<activity android:name="MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>`

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI Yes I tried it but it didn’t help